# Force controller function to wait for service function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to check data availability in controller, that is provided by service. Service is using HTTP request to get some data - depending on response function is returning just true or false. Boolean value is returned to controller and `if` is executed on returned value.

But it doesn't work, controller doesn't wait for value, in debugger the variable is "undefined", `if` is executed as `false` and controller is going to the next code.

As there is HTTP request I am using .then for response handling in service. I tried also to use `promise` and `.then` in controller. None of them helped.

Here is a code from controller:

```
var t5 = PermissionService.permissions.gotRequiredPermissions();
   if (t5) {
       // some processing
   }
```

and here is function from service:

```
function gotRequiredPermissions() {
        ApiService.getUserPermissions().then(function successCallback(response) {
            //processing

            //returns true or false

        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            return false;
        });             
    }
```

Function in controller is called, then function is service is called, then controller skips the `if` as t5 is undefined, goes to code after `if` and then, when controller finish it's stuff, service process the `successCallback` and returns value.

Comment: are you using $http ?

Comment: Yes, in "ApiService" there is $http used for request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify `gotRequiredPermissions()` function to return a promise:

```
function gotRequiredPermissions() {
    return ApiService.getUserPermissions().then(function successCallback(response) {
        //processing

        //returns true or false

    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        return false;
    });             
}
```

In controller you should get the result:

```
PermissionService.permissions.gotRequiredPermissions().then(result=> console.log(result))
```